# Port forwarding ADSL

Tags: port-forwarding, port, http, forwarding

I have a TP-LINK TD-8817 as my ADSL Router, and a TP-LINK TL-MR3420 as a WiFi Router.

I've opened port 80 as can be seen by this result from a port forwarding tester:

[image]

The problem is, whenever I access my public IP (125.xxx.xxx.xxx:80), it's still returning to my router port. I expected it to return to my computer's IP address and port, 192.168.0.102.

[image]

Client:

```
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.102(Preferred)
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
 Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 24 Juli 2013 15:34:29
 Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 24 Juli 2013 21:34:06
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
 DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

My forwarded ports on the ADSL modem:

```
Rule     Application     Protocol    Start Port  End Port    Local IP Address
1            HTTP_Server    ALL         80          80         192.168.1.100
2            HTTP_Server    ALL         443         443        192.168.1.100
```

WiFi router:

```
   ID   Service Port    Internal Port   IP Address  Protocol    Status  Modify
1        80                 80        192.168.0.102     All          Enabled    Modify Delete
```

I have no idea how to resolve this. Any thoughts?

Comment: The results you are getting are to be expected based on your current configuration.  Why are you forwarding traffic on port 80 to both `192.168.1.100` and `192.168.1.102`? that does not seem right.  Your current configuraton is attempting to access the http server of the modem itself hence the prompt.  If you were to input your username and password to your modem you would be redirect not to your http server on .102 but to the internal http server of the modem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ADSL router already uses the TCP80 port for its remote administration interface.

From here you have 2 solutions :

## 1) Change Router interface port

If you can find any parameter in your router's configuration for this, change it to, for example, 8080.
After that your NAT should work fine.

## 2) Change your external HTTP port

If your router does not support the modification of its remote interface TCP port, you will have to choose another port for your website, which is often unwanted.

In your port forwarding settings, change this :

```
Rule     Application     Protocol    Start Port  End Port    Local IP Address
1            HTTP_Server    ALL         80          80         192.168.1.100
```

To this :

```
Rule     Application     Protocol    Start Port  End Port    Local IP Address
1            HTTP_Server    ALL       8080        8080         192.168.1.100
```

And this :

```
ID   Service Port    Internal Port   IP Address    Protocol   
1       80              80        192.168.0.102     All
```

To this:

```
ID   Service Port    Internal Port   IP Address    Protocol   
1     8080              80        192.168.0.102     All
```

Comment: thank you, yes I tried that way too. but doesn't work. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried accessing it from an external device ? Some SOHO routers don't have a loopback interface and are unable to query themselves...

Comment: Yeah!!! Finally works. 
I just realize that, thank you Kwaio!